# BLE GATT server name

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, device, gatt

I've created an android app of BLE GATT server, but I can't find where I write the name of the GATT Server, I mean the device name that appears in search.

I tried both
https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt

and can't find where the name of the device being written?
how BLE search decide what name to show?

Comment: Have you tried [BluetoothAdapter.setName("MyGattServerName")](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#setName(java.lang.String))?

Comment: Thanks,
just tried 
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().setName("MyGattServerName");

and it worked!!!
Thanks again.

Comment: Great. I wasn't sure about it (had it in some old experimental code) and didn't bother to test it. You can add it as an answer yourself, if you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tried:

BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().setName("MyGattServerNa‌​me");

and it worked!!!